# NamespaceError in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have below HTML tags and I am trying to find element by Xpath. But I am always getting an error.
How do I resolve it?

NamespaceError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'cms1500AddInputForm:memberNumber' contains unresolvable namespaces.

driver.find_element_by_xpath('cms1500AddInputForm:memberNumber')

HTML code

Comment: You can have a try with this `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "cms1500AddInputForm:memberNumber")`

Comment: Can you please show the HTML that includes this string ?

Comment: Please provide HTML code  or the URL so that xpath can be suggested

Comment: `cms1500AddInputForm:memberNumber` is the problem xpath. Add html.